# Date and hour on the phone in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, date, time

Well, I want a Text view to resolve the date and the time of the phone, and then add it as a variable in my email intent to be sent. How do I do this? I dont event know where to start.

Comment: as u said u dnt knw wher to strt so i suggest u to start with this link http://developer.android.com/training/index.html & for email http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to fetch the current data and time and show it in a textview without user intervention? If yes, you can do so using the below code

```
DateFormat dateFmt = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM, SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM);
String strDate = dateFmt.format(new Date());
```

and then you can show this string in your text view. and you can send the same in your email intent as part of your subject or body.

Answer (score 1):

> - I want a Text view to resolve the date and the time of the phone

The current date and time of the device can be retrieved using `Date date = new Date()`.

To display the date in a TextView using the user's default formatting:

```
String dateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);
textView.setText(dateTime);
```

> - and then add it as a variable in my email intent to be sent

Assuming you want to include it in the message body:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textView.getText().toString());
```